# CAGradientLayer is not working properly

Tags: ios, uiview, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to create a UITableViewCell with a gradient background. I don't understand why but there is a white blank space at the right of the UITableView. I tried by settings a solid color but the result hasn't changed.

This is my UITableViewCell class.

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        let gl = CAGradientLayer()
        gl.frame = self.bounds
        //gl.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor as CGColor, UIColor.red.cgColor as CGColor]
        gl.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(gl)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

And it looks like this. (The blue on is the table row)
[image]

What is happening? If I set a background from XCode, it shows everything fine. It just doesn't fit the screen size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the cell comes out of the nib at one size, but then is later resized as it is placed into the interface. But your layer is added much earlier than the cell resizing, and the layer is *not* resized when the cell is resized. Therefore the layer ends up at the *wrong* size.

A good approach here is to keep a reference to your gradient layer and size the layer in a `layoutSubviews` override:

```
class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    var gl : CAGradientLayer?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        let gl = CAGradientLayer()
        gl.frame = self.bounds
        gl.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gl.zPosition = -1
        self.layer.addSublayer(gl)
        self.gl = gl
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.gl?.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I've tried to add the CAGradientLayer within a method which is called in the cellForRowAt method. But the result's not changed.

Comment: If you want to do this in your cell subclass, keep a reference to the gradient layer and set its frame in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Added example code and screen shot showing that it works.